# How to remove chaining in this code using behavior subjects?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

How can we refactor the following code to remove the chaining using behaviorsubjects, so that the failure of one function call does not affect the UI which uses the data from the other function calls?

```
this.service.getElementById(this.elementId)
  .pipe(mergeMap((element) =>
    zip(
      of(element),
      this.service.getReport(this.elementId, this.year, this.month)
    ))
  )
  .pipe(mergeMap(([element, report]) =>
    zip(
      of(element),
      of(report),
      this.service.getChanges(this.elementId, report.lineId)
    ))
  )
  .subscribe(([element, report, changes]) => {
    this.paymentProvider = provider;
    this.mapToSummary(report);
    this.lineId = report.lineId;
    this.changes = changes;
  })
```

Comment: This can be simplified without using a subject. Why do you want to use a BehaviorSubject?

Comment: @BizzyBob I need to use behaviorSubjects because each of the data are updated asynchronously. How can we simplify it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can achieve this:

```js
this.service
  .getElementById(this.elementId)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((element) => {
      const report$ = this.service
        .getReport(this.elementId, this.year, this.month)
        .pipe(
          catchError(() => of(null)),
          shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
        );

      const changes$ = report$.pipe(
        mergeMap((report) =>
          !report
            ? of(null)
            : this.service
                .getChanges(this.elementId, report.lineId)
                .pipe(catchError(() => of(null)))
        )
      );

      return forkJoin({
        element: of(element),
        report: report$,
        changes: changes$,
      });
    })
  )
  .subscribe(({ element, report, changes }) => {
    // do whatever you want here
    // remember that now report and changes can be null
  });
```

This will make sure that if any fail, it's not erroring for the whole observable.